# How to combine two queries and use results of first one as output for the second

Tags: c++, sqlite

## Tables

I have the following tables:

```
 entite              var_entite                 variation
ID | NAME        ID_entite|id_var                ID | NAME
1  | x1            1      |    1                  1 | y1
2  | x2            1      |    2                  2 | y2
3  | x3            1      |    3                  3 | y3
                   2      |    1                  4 | y4
                   2      |    4                  5 | y5
                   3      |    2
                   3      |    5
```

---

## Schema

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITE (ID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME STRING)

CREATE TABLE VAR_ENTITE(ID_ENTITE INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                        ID_VARIATION INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                        FOREIGN KEY (ID_ENTITE) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID),
                        FOREIGN KEY (ID_VARIATION) REFERENCES VARIATIONS(ID);

CREATE TABLE VARIATIONS (ID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME STRING)
```

---

## Problem

I am using `sqlite3`. the `?` represent the input variables.

1- For every entity `x` in table `entite` we want to select its variations `y`

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, v.name FROM var_entite ve 
       JOIN entite as e ON e.id_entite = ve.id_entite 
       JOIN variations as v ON v.id = ve.id_var;
```

2- For every **selected** entity in the previous query we**select** all the **rest** entities having the same varitions.

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, v.name FROM var_entite ve 
       JOIN entite as e ON e.id = ve.id 
       JOIN variations as v ON v.id = ve.id_var
       where e.id <> ? and v.name =? ;
```

- `e.id_entite <> ?` for the rest of entities having a different entity from query 1
- `v.name =?` if an entity has the same variation as the one returned in **1** then we select it

**My questions are the following:**

- How can we combine these 2 queries in order to get the same results?
- If we combine the queries will the querying become faster?

---

## Example

Query 1:

```
1,x1,y1
1,x1,y2
1,x1,y3
2,x2,y1
2,x2,y4
3,x3,y2
3,x3,y5
```

Query 2 outputs for entity with **id = 1**

```
    2,x2,y1
    3,x3,y2
```

Query 2 output for entity with **id = 2**

```
    1,x1,y1
    etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of queries can be reused by using subqueries.

In this case, the subquery does not need any names, so it does not need to do any joins:

```sql
SELECT e.id, e.name, v.name
FROM var_entite ve
   JOIN entite as e ON e.id = ve.id_entite
   JOIN variations as v ON v.id = ve.id_variation
WHERE e.id <> ?
  AND v.id IN (SELECT id_variation
               FROM var_entite
               WHERE id_entite = ?)
```

Comment: e.id <> ? should be different from what? i didn't really understand what should be the input? the same for id_entite

Comment: Is it possible to insert **e.id** in the subquery in order to extract all the **id_varations** that have an**id_entite != e.id**

Comment: Both `?` are the ID of the original entity (1 or 2 in your examples).